# NSIS execute external jar but not working

Tags: java, nsis

I run this on HM NIS Edit which work but when I launch using a EXE. The script is able to launch but my Jar is not functioning 10 out of 10. Did anyone come across the same issue?
Could it be (java.exe*32) has to do with it?

On W7 64bit:

```
!define S_NAME "dev"
Name "${S_NAME}"
OutFile "${S_NAME}.exe"

#!include FileFunc.nsh
#!insertmacro GetParameters

#Var CMD_ARGS

RequestExecutionLevel user

# Installer sections
Section -Main SEC0000
#${GetParameters} $CMD_ARGS

HideWindow
nsExec::Exec "java -jar D:\software.jar -n 0"

Quit
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problably having problems with the uac.

Check this solution:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in